# How to tween model changes in react or where to resolve collision for fluent pure rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, redux

### My State

I have a array of items in the following format:

`[{ left: 0 }, { left: 10 }, { left: 20 }]`

I can add an item `{ left: 30 }` to this array:

`[{ left: 0 }, { left: 10 }, { left: 20 }, { left: 30 }]`

I can add a duplicate item `{ left: 20 }` to this array:

`[{ left: 0 }, { left: 10 }, { left: 20 }, { left: 20 }, { left: 30 }]`

### My View

I have to render these items on a plane, at position x, where x is their left property.

`[{ left: 0 }, { left: 10 }, { left: 20 }]` renders `|item1 item2 item3|`

`[{ left: 0 }, { left: 10 }, { left: 20 }, { left: 30 }]` renders `|item1 item2 item3 item4 item5|`

When there is a duplicate, I have to resolve this duplication by shifting elements left or right.
So

`[{ left: 0 }, { left: 10 }, { left: 20 }, { left: 20 }, { left: 30 }]` renders `|item1 item2 item3 item4 item5|`

So they should not overlap.

I can add new items one by one, where new item can have any left property multiple of 10.

In case of an overlap, items should resolve the overlap by shifting right.

This could result in multiple items to be shifted to the right.

Example:

`[{ left: 0 }, { left: 10 }, { left: 20 }, { left: 20 }, { left: 30 }, { left: 40 }]`

resolving this requires shifting both items with left property
 30 and 40. It becomes

`[{ left: 0 }, { left: 10 }, { left: 20 }, { left: 30 }, { left: 40 }, { left: 50 }]`

The shifting of items have to be animated/tweened.
How can I enforce this requirement in React and flux architecture?

A. Resolve overlap within stores by tweaking left properties of the model, reflecting change in the view with tween.
   - How do I reflect a change to tween in React Components?
   - How do I resolve overlap?

Comment: somewhat related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198479/whats-a-react-js-friendly-way-to-animate-a-list-reordering

Comment: something like this: http://react.rocks/example/React-motion_reorder_list

Comment: I've used react motion before, and it works. Straight up.

However, if you want full control, testability, and descrete states that redux offers, then like me you may need to do things manually...

I'm about to start, if I make a library out of this I'll try and remember to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like [React Motion](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion).
It can tween transitions between lists like you described.