# Flicker during React animations

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, animation, dom

**Background**: I am using Web Animations API (native JavaScript) to translate elements (div's) horizontally to visualize sorting algorithms. I am also using React which handles the rendering of these elements by the JSX.

**Problem**: There is a screen flickering after I have completed the swapping animations (using Web Animations) but before I have set the state (`useState` hook) of the now-ordered elements. It is not recommended to manipulate the DOM outside of the React component, but this appears to be the only option because React does not appear to support animations natively for this use case. The workaround I have employed is reversing/cancelling the animations after they have completed for the elements, quickly restoring them to their original (React-managed) positions, and calling `setState()`. This results in intermittent flickering of the original unsorted state and occasional improper rendering (elements offscreen).

Similar implementation to [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54738766/7800407).

**Code**:

*Animation Code*:

```js
    let previousAnimation = Promise.resolve();
    for (const animation of swapAnimations) {
        // Redacted code to compute $leftBlock and $rightBlock [...]

        previousAnimation = Promise.all([previousAnimation]).then(() => {
            // Timing options
            const timing = {
                duration: 1000,
                fill: "forwards",
            };

            // Left element moves right
            const leftMove = [
                {transform: `translateX(${LEFT_POSITION}px)`, offset: 0.0},
                {transform: `translateX(${RIGHT_POSITION}px)`, offset: 1.0}
            ];
    
            // Right element moves left
            const rightMove = [
                {transform: `translateX(${RIGHT_POSITION}px)`, offset: 0.0},
                {transform: `translateX(${LEFT_POSITION}px)`, offset: 1.0}
            ];

            // Play animations
            const leftAnimation = leftBlock.animate(leftMove, timing);
            const rightAnimation = rightBlock.animate(rightMove, timing);

            // Chain animations such that next pair of animations start 
            // after the current pair of animations finishes
            return Promise.all([leftAnimation.finished, rightAnimation.finished]);
        }).catch((reason) => console.log(new Error(reason)));
    }
```

*Restore React State Workaround*:

```js
// Outside of previous code's loop
previousAnimation = previousAnimation.then(() => {
    for (const block of blocks) {
        // Restore initial state
        const restoreAnimation = block.animate({
            transform: `translateX(0)`,
        }, {
            // Options to try to fix screen flicker
            duration: 0,
            fill: "forwards",
            easing: "step-end",
            delay: 1
        });
        restoreAnimation.finished.then(() => {
            // Also tried this, not sure if it changes anything to cancel
            // finished animations
            block.getAnimations().forEach((animation) => animation.cancel());
        });

        // $sortedBlocks is computed earlier on
        // I have tried moving this line to before, in-line with, and after 
        // the restore code above. The screen flicker persists
        setBlocks(sortedBlocks);
    }
});
```

**Potential Solutions**:

1. **Timing manipulation** did not seem to work for me thus far. I tried making the restore animation as fast as possible by setting the `KeyframeEffect()` options but it still renders the flicker unfortunately. Is there anything else I can try related to this?
2. **React Transition Group** is natively supported but does not appear to fit the use case as it only appears to work for components entering/exiting DOM as per this [guide](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/). The elements I am trying to animate are already in the DOM, so Hooks don't really apply I believe.
3. **External React animation libraries** (React Spring, Framer Motion, etc.) would be ideally be avoided. I have not explored any of these as I trying to not import any third-party libraries or frameworks. Would one of these work for this task? Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56778988/animate-when-items-in-a-list-change-order-with-react)?
4. **Window.requestAnimationFrame()** is another native JS animation method that could work as per [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). But as this would still be a non-React implementation, it seems probable that the DOM rendering issues I am experiencing would persist.
5. **Separate JS from React** to remove the animated elements from the React DOM tree. I am attempting to create a React single-page application and would prefer a React solution, but I suppose this is a viable solution.

**Question** (TLDR): The screen flickers after the JS animation finishes because I have to restore the pre-animation DOM quickly in order to maintain React state for proper rendering. How can I fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Update**: I have also looked into CSS Transitions/Animations. This is also not feasible because the animations are dynamic and based on element positions which vary greatly. Thus these animations cannot be reduced into finite CSS classes unfortunately.

Comment: *React does not appear to support animations natively for this use case*. Can you give a small example of why you think this is so?

Comment: @GetSet Just from a simple search, nothing comes up beyond obsolete React.js references to [React Transition Group](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/animation.html). Native JS animation solutions that manipulate the DOM seem to conflict with React rendering when I set state.

Comment: Changing the element's x,y position will move it and doing so successively will give it motion (animation). So I'm wondering why you dont think this will work with react?

Comment: It does work, which I am doing in the code above. But if you manipulate the DOM using native JS (i.e. outside React), then you run the risk of inconsistent and unpredictable rendering. I am asking for a solution or alternative to this.


For this reason, I have come up with the restorative workaround (also above). But this causes the screen flickering which the basis of this post.

Comment: There is no fix. You'll have to go a different route. But then again, I'm not too quite sure why you have to "restore" the state. What happens when you dont?

Comment: Because if I don't then the React re-render when I `setState()` for the DOM elements, they don't appear correctly. This is because React treats the UI declaratively and the JS animations are outside that. ([Source](https://react.dev/learn/reacting-to-input-with-state))